# I'm getting this error in a string concanination line Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in

Tags: php, string, syntax-error

I'm tyring to have an install file create a config file using the string bellow but I keep getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in...

```
$tempcon = '
<?php
// Give Usage string for Config File
if(isset($_GET["gimi"])) {
  die('"' . str_replace('\\','\\\\',__FILE__) . '"'); // <--- The error is on this line!
}
$dbhost = "'. $_POST["dbhost"] .'";             // Database Host Address
$dbname = "'. $_POST["dbname"] .'";             // Database Name
$dbuser = "'. $_POST["dbuser"] .'";             // Database Username
$dbpass = "'. $_POST["dbpass"] .'";             // Database Password

?>';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Robert

Comment: LOL, I didn't even notice that all that php block is being put in a variable, I was too busy counting slashes and single quotes on the error line :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `'` in the string.

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: @RobertH in `die` there are `'`s, they need to be escaped

Answer (score 0):

Your last four string assignments appear to be broken. I would suggest using a heredoc/nowdoc instead to avoid problems.

Edit: outside of that, it seems you're writing a php file, with php, to dynamically connect to another database, controlled by the user. This has a bad smell... could you describe what you're trying to do a little more? There must be a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: I'm writing an install script that uses  dynamic inputs from the user,  it was working fine until I added the "if (isset " protion

Answer (score 0):

The parse error you're (currently) getting is because of the quotes on the array index - although your die() is also going to give you trouble, as Musa noted. Better solution: use [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc).

```
<?php
$tempcon = <<<PHPCODE
<?php
// Give Usage string for Config File
if(isset({$_GET["gimi"]})) {
    die('"' . str_replace('\\','\\\\',__FILE__) . '"'); // <--- The error is on this line!
}
$dbhost = "'. {$_POST["dbhost"]} .'";             // Database Host Address
$dbname = "'. {$_POST["dbname"]} .'";             // Database Name
$dbuser = "'. {$_POST["dbuser"]} .'";             // Database Username
$dbpass = "'. {$_POST["dbpass"]} .'";             // Database Password

?>
PHPCODE;
```